# Blackberry Java Sqlite Many Record Inserting

Tags: java, sqlite, blackberry

How can I insert many rows(~100k) on sqlite database for blackberry java app.? I tried this code:

```
Database d1; Statement st;

URI dbURI1 = URI.create("file:///SDCard/xxx.db")  if (DatabaseFactory.exists(dbURI1)) {
    d1 = DatabaseFactory.open(dbURI1); } else {
    d1 = DatabaseFactory.create(dbURI1);
    st = d1.createStatement("Insert into..................(for 100 k rows)");

    st.prepare();
    st.execute();
    st.close(); }
```

and also I tried this

st = d1.createStatement("Insert into......");

```
    st.prepare();
    st.execute();
    st.close();
```

st = d1.createStatement("Insert into......");

```
    st.prepare();
    st.execute();
    st.close();
```

.
.
.
for 100k rows.

Eclipse started to be extreme slow and I couldn't debug it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Public void InsertData ()
{
Database d;
try
{
URI myURI = URI.create("file:///SDCard/Databases/" +"Test.db"); 
d = DatabaseFactory.open(myURI);

Statement st = d.createStatement("INSERT INTO testtable(id,name) " + "VALUES (1,’Arun’)");
st.prepare();
st.execute();
st.close();
d.close();
add(new RichTextField("Values Inserted"));
}
catch ( Exception e ) 
{ 
System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
e.printStackTrace();
add(new RichTextField("Error: "+e.toString()));
}

}
```

Comment: This is ok but the problem is eclipse is so slow and doesn't allow me to debug. By this way I need to add 100k rows. Do you know any other efficient way?

Comment: May be due to insertion of many records, it may get slow. Sorry i don't have any other idea in this.